# Operation did not complete successfully because of virus - svn checkout

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

trying to checkout my develop branch but getting error:-

`Can't open file:`

`'D:\Code\develop\.svn\pristine\9f\9dffg.......sdf.svn-base'`

`Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or`

`potentially unwanted software`

how can i go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2):

you have to configure your virus scanner software to exclude the working copy paths from checking.